# Long/Int in scala to hex string

Tags: scala, hex, long-integer

With `Integer.toString(1234567, 16).toUpperCase() // output: 12D68` could help to convert an `Int` to Hex string.

How to do the same with Long?

`Long.toString(13690566117625, 16).toUpperCase() // but this will report error`

Comment: What error did you get? What if you used "`13690566117625L`" with an L at the end?

Comment: @kennytm, `Long.toString(13690566117625L, 16).toUpperCase()`, it would say `error: too many arguments for method toString: ()String`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're looking for [`RichLong.toHexString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Long.html#toHexString:String):

```
scala> 13690566117625L.toHexString
res0: String = c73955488f9
```

And the uppercase variant:

```
scala> 13690566117625L.toHexString.toUpperCase
res1: String = C73955488F9
```

#### Edit

This also available for `Int` via [`RichInt.toHexString`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Int.html#toHexString:String):

```
scala> 42.toHexString
res4: String = 2a
```

Comment: The links are dead

Answer (score 15):

```
val bigNum: Long   = 13690566117625L
val bigHex: String = f"$bigNum%X"
```

Use `%X` to get uppercase hex letters and `%x` if you want lowercase.

Comment: Also you can do padding e.g. with zeros to a length of 16 like this: `f"$bigNum%016X"`

Comment: Yes indeed. You can also add the standard hex designation to the formatted output: `f"$myNum%#x"` results in `0x1c4`. A concise means to express values in many different hex formats.

Answer (score 5):

I've found `f"0x$int_val%08X"` or `f"0x$long_val%16X"` to work great when you want to align a value with leading zeros.

```
scala> val i = 1
i: Int = 1

scala> f"0x$i%08X"
res1: String = 0x00000001

scala> val i = -1
i: Int = -1

scala> f"0x$i%08X"
res2: String = 0xFFFFFFFF

scala> val i = -1L
i: Long = -1

scala> f"0x$i%16X"
res3: String = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several errors. First of all, the number `13690566117625` is too large to fit in an `int` so you need to add an `L` prefix to indicate that it's a `long` literal. Second, `Long` does not have a `toString` method that takes a radix (unlike `Integer`).

Solution:

```
val x = 13690566117625L
x.toHexString.toUpperCase
```

Answer (score 0):

The benefit of using Scala is the ability to use Java libraries.

So, you could implement :

```
import scala.util.Try
val longToHexString = Try(java.lang.Long.toString(13690566117625, 16)) // handle exceptions if any
```